# Query with exists and not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, subquery

I have a database which contains 5 tables.

```
COURSES (***CourseID***, CourseName, Credit)

TEACHERS (***SSN***, Name)

OFFER (***CourseID***, ***SSN***)

STUDENTS (***StudentID***, Name, Department)

ENROLL (***StudentID***, ***CourseID***, Semester)
```

And I want to find the course names that are enrolled at least one 'Automotive Engineering' student. But also that course must not be offered by 'Angel'. What I mean is courses that are enrolled at least one 'Automotive Engineering' student and not offered (taught) by 'Angel'.

I got the below answer from another question but I don't know how to go from here.

```
select C.CourseName
from Courses C
-- A student from the selected department is enrolled in this course
where exists (
    select 1
    from Enroll E
    inner join Students S on S.StudentId = E.StudentId
    where S.Department = 'Automotive Engineering' and E.CourseID = C.CourseID
)
```

The above code gives me the course names that are enrolled at least one 'Automotive Engineering' student but how can I check that the course is not offered by 'Angel'?

Comment: please do not do what you just tried to do, which was remove the entire question. That is not how this site works. The question stays and so do the answers to help others in future.

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question. Don't change a question in a way that invalidates reasonable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exists` approach that filters on course to which at least one student of the relevant participate is fine. Starting from your existing query, you can add more joins to bring the course teacher and filter out `'Angel'`:

```
select C.CourseName
from Courses C
inner join Offer O on O.CourseId = C.CourseID
inner join Teachers T on T.SSN = O.SSN
where 
    exists (
        select 1
        from Enroll E
        inner join Students S on S.StudentId = E.StudentId
        where S.Department = 'Automotive Engineering' and E.CourseID = C.CourseID
    )
    and T.Name <> 'Angel'
```